# Calling Webservice using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, json, mobile, cordova

I would like to ask for some running examples/tutorials for invoking json webservices using jquery mobile.

I'm trying to develop my first mobile application and was not able to find a fruitful example yet.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

First I'd check out the examples in the official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

That should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var serviceUrl = 'http://' + _SERVER_ADDRESS + '/YOURSERVICE.svc/' + method;
    var jsonCallbackMethod = 'spycallback49328572';

    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : serviceUrl,
        jsonpCallback : jsonCallbackMethod,
        data : params,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        timeout : 11*1000 // Necessary in order to detect not found(404) error
    })
    .done(function(response) { <success code> })
    .fail(function(xhr) { <failure code> });
```